# Display Selected Variations in WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have 2 variations, colour and size. Lets say I picked the colour blue and the size medium.

I want to showcase the chosen attributes in a div:

```
Colour: Blue
Size: Medium
```

Then if I changed my size to large, it would dynamically change to:

```
Colour: Blue
Size: Large
```

I have managed to work it this way, can anyone tell me if this is good practice or not?

```js
function displayVals() {
    var sizeVal = $("#colour").val();
    var sizeVal = $("#size").val() [];
    $("p.colour").html( colorVal );
    $("p.size").html(sizeVal);
}

$("select").change(displayVals);
displayVals();
```

Which then displayed in HTML like so:

```html
<p class="colour"></p>
<p class="size"></p>
```

I have tested and this way works, are there other ways etc?

Comment: Not on "change" event, but instead dedicated variation events as `show_variation` and `hide_variation`… see https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bwoocommerce%5d%20show_variation

Comment: can you share code you have tried?

Comment: @allenski I have updated the question